# Git repo corrupted while switching branches

Tags: git

Using Eclipse I tried to switch from my branch 1566-cm11a to a different branch called 1694-smartthings. The checkout failed because I had a file explorer opened to a directory that doesn't exist in the target branch. Now the repository seems to be totally corrupted.

When I try to change to the 1694-smartthings branch I get messages like:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.airquality/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.allplay/README.md
        addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.amazondashbutton/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

When I try to change to the master branch I get messages like:

```
M       addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.airquality/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
M       addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.allplay/README.md
D       addons/binding/org.openhab.binding.allplay/src/main/java/org/openhab/binding/allplay/internal/discovery/AllPlaySpeakerDiscoveryService.java
```

I'm not sure what the D and M prefixes are but I assume they are Deleted and Modified, right?

Is there a way to recover from this short of starting over?

Comment: `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout` ... Please Google this error message to get some help.  Nothing is "corrupted" in your repo.  Rather, sloppy Git etiquette is the likely cause of this.

Comment: Type `git status` and tell us what you see.  Is the file `README.md` shown as being an untracked file?

Comment: Yes, README.md is an untracked file

Comment: The file `README.md` is tracked in one branch by Git but untracked in the other branch.  This is the cause of the problem.  Do you intend for this file to be versioned by Git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I googled the message and most answers recommend doing a `git reset --hard` or `git stash`. But in your comment below indicates this isn't what you would do. What do you recommend?

Comment: Yes, that is generally an option, but you have a bigger problem if there are untracked files which are tracked in the other branch.  You need to resolve this first before stashing or resetting.  I'm trying to give you a long term fix here.  If you want a quick and dirty short term solution, the answer below should work.

Comment: I have 2 branches: 1566-cm11a and 1694-smartthings. When the problem occurred 1566-cm11a was active. There were no uncommitted files and the working directory was clean in both branches and in master. Thanks for your help. I am glad that you think my repo is not corrupted (and therefore I assume this is recoverable).

Comment: As I already mentioned, the files listed may have the problem that they are versioned in one branch but not the other.  You need to resolve this.  Should those `.md` files always be versioned?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did a `git stash` and after that I still have 17 files that are untracked. I then tried `git reset --hard` but that did not clean up the untracked files. It is possible that I have files versioned in 1566-cm11a but not in 1694-smartthings. Earlier I ran the following commands: `git co master, git fetch upstream, git rebase upstream/master, git co 1566-cm11a, git rebase upstream/master `. Can you give me a suggestion how to this.

Comment: You are in a mess now.  Stashing won't do anything to untracked files, because they are not part of Git.  As I keep saying, you need to figure out whether you want those untracked files to be versioned, or whether you want them to be deleted.  You can't really have both.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no important changes that were not commited, you can just run `git reset --hard` and try again. This command will reset your workspace to exactly the same state of the branch 1566-cm11a.

WARNING: This command will erase any non commited modification.

If you have made code changes that you want to bring to your other branch, then run

```
git stash
git checkout 1694-smartthings
git stash pop
```

Comment: No, this is not what I would do here.  The OP most likely has a handful of files which are versioned in only one of the two branches.

Comment: This would not fail the checkout. It would only fail the checkout if the files were modified in the source branch, and the target branch does not have that files.

Comment: But this is precisely what I suspect; in one branch those `.MD` files were added, possibly unintentionally, while in the other destination branch they were just untracked files.  In any case, I don't think a hard reset is likely to be a good long term solution here.

Comment: Yes, probably. Well, I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question, but I would ask if that files were explicitly change by him in his branch.